# PHP, email attachment with Form elements not working

Tags: forms, php

I know this has been covered 100 times but I still can't seem to find the right way to get this to work.  Sometimes this code will work and send an email with attachment, sometimes the attachment will come through, sometimes it won't send at all.  I've tried PHPMailer() and when I attach something the body won't send and the attachment won't come through either.  Tried swiftmailer and the attachment won't work on that.  Maybe it's my server IPage?  Not sure if i need to change something in the php.ini file.  But here is what I have, maybe I'm missing something

```
    if($category == 'music' || $category == 'sports'){
  $to[1] = 'post@tweetymail.com';
  $to[2] = '1234567890@tumblr.com';
  $to[3] = 'website.1234567890@blogger.com';
}

  $soc_post = substr($post,0,139);



  $subject[1] = $title;
  $subject[2] = 'Website - ' . $title;
  $subject[3] = 'Site - ' . $title;

       $message[1] = '';
  $message[2] = $url_field . ' ' . str_replace("rnrn"," ",$soc_post);
  $message[3] = '<a href="'.$url_field.'">'.$new_url. '</a> ' . str_replace("rnrn"," ",$soc_post);



for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){

    $fileatt = $_FILES['blog_pic']['tmp_name'];
    $fileatt_type = $$_FILES['blog_pic']['type'];
    $fileatt_name = $_FILES['blog_pic']['name'];

         $email_message = $message[$i];
         $headers = "From: Website Blog <blog@website.com>";

         $file=fopen($fileatt,'rb');
         $data=fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
         fclose($file);

         $semi_rand=md5(time());
         $mime_boundary ="==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

         $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
         "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
         " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

         $email_message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
              "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
              "Content-Type:text/html; chartset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
        $email_message .= "\n\n";

        $data=chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

        $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
        "Content-Type:{$fileatt_type};\n" .
        " name=\"{$fileatt_name }\"\n" .
                    //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
                    //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
        $data .= "\n\n" .
        "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";   

    mail($to[$i], $subject[$i], $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: You have an additional `$` on the type: `$fileatt_type = $$_FILES['blog_pic']['type'];`. Just a typo? And I would definitely use something like swiftmailer if you want to send more that just plain text.

Comment: do your self a favour use [swiftmailier](http://swiftmailer.org/), or [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)